# How to configure the monitored services for an entire host group or folder?

Tags: check-mk

This should be easy to configure, but I do not find the menu entry for this in the Checkmk Web Interface:

I have folders and host groups with many hosts listed there. My goal is to define the monitored services for all hosts in this folder or group. How can I achieve this without editing every single host via Setup → Host → (hostname) → Edit Services?

Answer (score 0):

There is a rule set called "Disabled services". You can use it to disable services based on several conditions.